# How to minimize, maximize and restore down through buttons in java?

Tags: java, custom-controls, customization, javafx

I'm creating a JavaFX 2.2 program, and need to create custom UI controls (just those ever-present minimize-maximize/restore-close buttons on the top). I need to create custom buttons for that purpose, simple till just creating.

I just need the real code for minimize and the maximize/restore buttons (close button was fairly a child's play). The minimize button restores the app to the taskbar. The maximize button, well, maximizes it to fit the user's screen and it toggles to restore button while maximized. When the restored button is clicked, the window gets restored to its initial size (1200x600).

I tried `stage.setSize(width, height);` in my fxml file for restore down, but it doesn't work (`stage` is highlited as the error, while the stage name is stage.)
I used

```
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

to set the default window as transparent.

The program(main file, not the controller) is:

```
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxmlfile.fxml"));       

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    stage.setTitle("Nothing here");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

The controller file with close action is:

```
@FXML
private void exitProgramAction(ActionEvent exitProgramEvent) {        
    System.out.println("Killing program...");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson there is hardly a problem in my code. I am a beginner in java and don't know the code for that purpose.

Comment: *"here is hardly a problem in my code."*  The point of an SSCCE in this situation is so that other people can quickly test ideas.  It's up to you though..

Comment: @AndrewThompson How would he post an example if his question is how to even create the code? He just wants to know the appropriate functions.

Comment: @PratikAnand Look up the documentation please. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html

Comment: @PratikAnand  Create a JavaFX app. (simplest you can), that does everything ***but*** what you cannot do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX entirely customized windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874664/javafx-entirely-customized-windows)

Comment: See the [add maximize property to stage](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-10376) feature added for [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html)

Comment: @jewelsea not so. I target just those minimize-maximize/restore features in this question. Dragging and all that will came as a question few days later

Answer (score 6):

To minimize the stage into task bar set an action for your minimize button similar to this:

```
    btnMinimize.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Stage stage = (Stage)((Button)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            // is stage minimizable into task bar. (true | false)
            stage.setIconified(true);
        }
    });
```

I use JavaFX 8 therefore I don't know if it will work with JavaFX 2.2

Answer (score 1):

In JavaFX8

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    //Maximized
    stage.setMaximized(true);

    //Restore down
    stage.setMaximized(false);
}
```

Comment: The same idea works with restoring from a minimized state.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your stage object in your main class. This only could be the stage object which could manipulate the Window.

See : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html

Answer (score 0):

code for minimize

```
  @FXML private void minimizeBut()
{
    Stage stage=(Stage) minimize.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setIconified(true);
}
```