# i make the stage transparent so i need the 3 stage buttons codes

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder, stage

these are the buttons i need

[image: these are the buttons i need .. click here]

my java program have multiple scenes ..

so i need the 3 codes that do the same  job as they do ....so i can make my own buttons and give them the codes in my java program ...

- close button .
- make bigger (also if bigger make smaller) .
- and the minimize button .

i have tried this for close button

```
{  @FXML
private void exitButton(ActionEvent event) {

    Platform.exit();
} }
```

and also how can i access to the main stage from multiple scenes  ?? ...

Comment: What have you tried so far. You need to show some effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to minimize, maximize and restore down through buttons in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591438/how-to-minimize-maximize-and-restore-down-through-buttons-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Button functions below they do as named

```
stage.setIconified(boolean);
stage.setMaximized(boolean);
stage.setFullScreen(boolean);
```

Comment: ty man ... but when i click just directly from the Iconified (i mean the buttom icon of the program)  ... it doesnt minimize ... how can i fix that ?