# javafx transparent window background with decorations

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make a transparent background for an application window in javafx. `scene.setFill(null)` seems to only work with `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT)`. Doc for `setFill` says

> Both a null value meaning paint no background and a Paint with transparency are supported, but what is painted behind it will depend on the platform.

but that doesn't make sense to me. It works (on windows 8) only with `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT` which removes the exit button and such which I still want.

I've looked at http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/completely_transparent_windows_stage_in and a few questions here.

Can this be done on windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX entirely customized windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874664/javafx-entirely-customized-windows)

Comment: @jewelsea so basically without hacking it out its not possible?

Comment: Related to: [how to make transparent scene and stage in javafx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033119/how-to-make-transparent-scene-and-stage-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

I've been tinkering with similar settings, and this works for me:

```
  @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

      primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
      primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
      primaryStage.setOpacity(0.5);
      primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("main.css")
            .toExternalForm());
      primaryStage.show();
}
```

...and the css

```
.root {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want a `TRANSPARENT` window, though. That's the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://github.com/Oshan96/CustomStage) library. It is a fully customizable JavaFx Stage (CustomStage). You can see in-detail description of how to use it in this [CustomStage Wiki](http://github.com/Oshan96/CustomStage/wiki)

It has,

- Window resizing
- Default action buttons and their behaviour (close, maximize/restore, minimize)
- Window dragging
- Window is automatically scaled as for screen resolution
- Very responsive
- Stylable
- Can achieve transparency
- Has in-built navigation panes and drawers
- etc.