# How to put a grey border around a background image in JavaFX?

Tags: css, javafx, background, border, stage

Is it possible to hide this grey border on this screen to make the hole window look like the scroll which is defined as backgroundimage in css?

Image with grey border
[image]

Image when stage is set to transparent
[image]

Thanks for your responses!

Greetings, Fabio

Comment: No, CSS does not apply to the `Stage` an you need to modify the stage style to accomplish this (set it to [`TRANSPARENT`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html#TRANSPARENT)). I btw recommend using an image that contains just the scroll without a border (or not using insets for the background) to avoid blocking user interaction with windows behind the transparent one in a larger area than needed...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033119/how-to-make-transparent-scene-and-stage-in-javafx