# Keep JavaFX Application Window Outer Elements Similar across All OS's

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, operating-system

I'm developing a JavaFX Application, In here, the outer elements of the JavaFX Window Changes across different Operating System's, i.e. The Position of Close, Minimize and Maximize Window is on left on Mac OS X and on the right in the Windows, Also there Shapes are Different as The OS Changes.

Also if the Application is Running Under OS X, it has drop shadow effect along the boundaries, which in case of Windows is Not Present :

[image: Here's how it is displayed in Mac OS X]

And Want My JavaFX Application to look exactly the Same, Regardless of Operating System, it is Being Run On. How Can i Achieve this ?

Comment: Use the [undecorator](https://github.com/in-sideFX/Undecorator) project.

Comment: Thank you, this is the thing i've been looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [undecorator](https://github.com/in-sideFX/Undecorator) project.

[image: undecorator]

> Decorate undecorated JavaFX stages with custom skin. This helper brings a custom look to your JavaFX stages.

See also:

- [JavaFX entirely customized windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874664/javafx-entirely-customized-windows)