# How to change border color and top bar of my window

Tags: css, javafx, colors, window, fxml

[image]

How to change this blue border of my window? I noticed that for example Spotify does not have that border. The second think is that I want to change the top white bar to, for example, red.  Any ideas?

Comment: have u tried with -fx-border-color:black;?

Comment: But  do I have to add it to the AnchorPane(Whole app is inside the AnchorPane) or where ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to set the color of the window border on Windows 10 (or any version that I know of).

However, looking at the Spotify application, it appears to me that they are using a custom border/title bar. I searched around a little bit and found another answer on customizing the entire window in JavaFX:
[JavaFX entirely customized windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874664/javafx-entirely-customized-windows)