# is there any way to change color of title bar in javafx

Tags: javafx, titlebar

Hi am a beginner in Javafx and wants to know that is there any way to change the color of title bar in Javafx.
 I tired looking up online but couldn't fine a proper suggestion.

Comment: Related to: [JavaFX entirely customized windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874664/javafx-entirely-customized-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Might not be possible as it belongs not to `JavaFX` app but to `OS windows manager`

Hard way would be not to use OS title bar but create your own.